# C# 7.3 readonly struct type "this" reference

Tags: c#

[readonly struct type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/reference-semantics-with-value-types#readonly-struct-type)

> The `this` reference, instead of a copy of the receiver, is always an `in` parameter passed by reference to the member method. This optimization saves more copying when you use a `readonly struct`.

What exactly does this mean? Does normal struct always make a copy when using "this" in the constructor?

Comment: If you have `readonly` value-type field or parameter and you want to call instance method on it, then you need to copy filed into local variable. If method guaranty to not change the struct, then you can call method directly on field: https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LglgNgPgAgzAAgM7AE4FcDGwEGUCMCA3gLABQClC81ALAgLIAUAlMQgL7ldk2oCmAQwAmAewB2EAJ7I0WHLgBMxclWqIY9ZmyKdu5GjGUBhFRSp8hYyTILJ8AblUXEAkROl5lSRU/OVDLXxWMzU1JHwAOm0/NR41QMZFENJ/MJ9o1liqeJc6RjgmMHE8QiQInWcw5AjMlmzKXICNLVoikqUaxUq08IyYqr0yDiA===

Comment: @PetSerAl well your point i is clear on the IL code, thanks. Seems the document has nothing to do with "this" in the constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you pass a struct as a parameter into a function, it makes a copy of the entire struct and gives it to the function.

Because you're using a *readonly struct*, you're essentially promising that it will never change.

When you use the (in) modifier on a function you pass it to, you're basically promising that you won't change the struct at all.  So, it's safe to pass in as a reference (a pointer, basically), instead of copying the entire thing defensively.

Comment: The MSDN quote specifically refers to calling instance methods of the struct itself. Seems to me that this is an entirely different concept to passing the struct "as a parameter into a function".